# Sfinae on function with either zero or one parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, overloading, sfinae

Consider the two following declarations:

```
template <class Function, 
          class = typename std::enable_if</*Function has zero argument*/>::type>
void apply(Function&& function);
template <class Function, 
          class... Dummy,
          class = typename std::enable_if</*Function has one argument*/>::type,
          class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Dummy) == 0>::type>
void apply(Function&& function, Dummy...);
```

What should I put in the `std::enable_if` in the first and second case to constrain the overload when the function has zero or one argument (regardless the type of the argument)?

Comment: First, I don't suggest using default template arg that way. And generally you can't know if the function can be called with one argument regardless the type. A dummy type that converts to anything may work in some cases, but not if the Function uses SFINAE.

Comment: Why would you care if a function can be called with one argument but you don't know the argument's type? If you don't know the argument's type, you can't possibly call it. The only scenarios where you can call it are those where you know the argument types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following traits may help you:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct arity : public arity<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct arity<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
{
};

// Do the same for other (11) combination of volatile, const, reference method.

// function pointer
template<class R, class... Args>
struct arity<R(*)(Args...)> : public arity<R(Args...)>
{};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct arity<R(Args...)> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
{
};
```

And then

```
template <class Function,
          class = typename std::enable_if<arity<typename std::remove_reference<Function>::type>::value == 0>::type>
void apply(Function&& function);
```

Comment: What about function objects?

Comment: You may complete the traits for functor class (with `operator ()`) and std::function`.

Comment: FWIW, there's [has_call](https://github.com/jamboree/boost.has_call) trait (note: not part of Boost)

Comment: How useless this is :S If you're going to limit yourself to function pointers just do:

    `template <class R>
    void apply(R(*function)());
    template <class R, class Arg0, class... Args>
    void apply(R(*function)(Arg0, Args...));`

If you're going to do this properly and support all sorts of callable types, this "function traits" nonsense won't ever work.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The given link completes this for some member `operator ()`.

Comment: It just doesn't work for a great many function objects (I like polymorphism). And with things like `std::greater<>` and polymorphic lambdas coming up it will fail even more often. It's an approach that was doomed from the start by unnecessarily limiting itself.